How to Manage Environment Variables for Dependabot PRs in Private Repositories?
I have a private repository where I've set up a dependabot.yml file to automatically raise pull requests for updates to actions and libraries.
However, the pull requests generated by Dependabot are unable to access environment variables. I've read that one solution is to add these variables in Settings → Secrets → Dependabot.
Is there a better way to manage environment variable access for Dependabot? I'd like to avoid having to add my environment variables in multiple places.
